# How to create custom function for callback - tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create custom function in Tensorflow, to save and print selected data after every epochs. So I created callback

```
class MyOwnFunction(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    print('Saving after {} epoch'.format(epoch + 1))
    model.save('C:/Users/model.h5')
    with open('C:/Users/trainingHistory', 'wb') as file_pi:
        pickle.dump(history.history, file_pi)

history = model.fit(
        train_generator,
        epochs=num_epochs,
        callbacks=[MyOwnFunction()],
        validation_data=validation_generator)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
NameError: name 'history' is not defined
```

Comment: Please show a complete traceback. I think I know the solution, but I need to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you bind to `history` in the global namespace does not exist until `model.fit` returns. That means it's not in the global namespace when `fit` calls your callback.

In addition to accessing a variable that doesn't exist, the lines that open the file overwrite the contents every time the callback executes.

The most likely solution is to move the following outside your function to the global namespace after binding `history`:

```
with open('C:/Users/trainingHistory', 'wb') as file_pi:
    pickle.dump(history.history, file_pi)
```